# Is there a Trait Level limit in Remnant: From The Ashes?

Tags: remnant-from-the-ashes

The [Trait](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Traits) system in Remnant: From The Ashes works similar to an Experience system in other games. When defeating enough enemies or obtaining a [Tome of Knowledge](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Tome+of+Knowledge), the player gains one trait point, which can be spent on any trait the player has "found" yet.

To my knowledge as of 2019, there are currently 35 different traits, and each trait can be improved until rank 20. This requires the player to obtain a total of 700 trait points to maximize every trait.

Is there a Trait Level limit in place which prevents maxing everything out?

Comment: I've read that in coop you get +1 for each Tome of Knowledge when another player pickup tome. Also option to reset world hint that there is no limit, keep resetting and completing the worlds or just play coop and you will be able to get *all* treats to maximum.

Comment: @Sinatr This is what I had thought as well, though there is always the possibility that there is a hard limit. I.e. even if you picked up a Tome of Knowledge, you would not gain a Trait point.

Comment: Actually, I've heard in one stream someone said "my character is 500 level and it is maximum", the *level* in this game is a total amount of skill points you can spend. So it seems 500 is maximum points you can have. Luckily some of skills are completely useless, e.g. after reaching maximum level you can *respec* (you get access to respec potion, which costs 2500 scrap after beating last boss) and get rid for +% experience skill.

Comment: Sorry for previous comment, streamer lied, I got [501](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1852725187) level myself and it goes up. Also UI to choose campaign (while there is only one currently) imply what we will have more content, means more traits. While maximum points could be rised via new DLCs, I am biasing on grindy nature of the game: it's motivating to play by the fact you CAN collect something. When you reach max = you will stop. So there is no max. And it's just slow enough. And traits in general just a small bonus anyway. But I am not dare to post answer ofc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Currently there is maximum limit of trait points - 640 points. It's enough to max all available traits.

Here is my char, I am not getting experience anymore (experience bar is empty) and I stop getting trait points when me or someone else pick up Tome of Knowledge.

[image]

I am still missing 3 traits, when I obtain them - they will be level 1 each, so

580 trait rank + 57 free points + 3 points = 640.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Each trait can have a max of 20 points, and there 32 traits in the game. So the max trait level is 640.

Whenever you get a trait point you can put it into whatever trait you want, so long as that trait doesn't already have 20 points in it.

Edit: [Source](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Traits)

Comment: Can you cite any sources for that, please?

Comment: @MechMK1, probably [this wiki](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Traits), there is currently indeed 32, but wiki is not full, e.g. this page miss [Heavy Hitter](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Heavy+Hitter). Could you rather provide your source of 35 max?

Comment: @Sinatr The wiki page we both linked to listed 35 traits in the version from 22nd of August. The three traits [Wisdom](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Wisdom), [Heavy Hitter](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Heavy+Hitter) and [Steady Breathing](https://remnantfromtheashes.wiki.fextralife.com/Steady+Breathing) have been removed since then. I assume they were data-mined and are not actually obtainable at the moment.

Comment: Aye, I've noticed some "silent" patches in Steam, bugfixes and balancing, it may all get changed. Btw, I am currently 150 level. If you wait for something like 2-3 weeks, I'll reach 500 and will post the answer =D

Comment: @Sinatr Yesterday I was 178, so we might hit max level at around the same time :D

Comment: 500 is not max. There was a reddit thread a few days ago where someone posted a screenshot of his maxed character with 640 trait points. I'm at work right now, but when I get home I can link it.

Comment: @Alakazooom, working hard for days? =D Btw, you are answering on another question. Unlimited != 640. Probably such questions can be only answered by cheaters (who got e.g. million of skill points, that's big enough) or developer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at 980 so I guess 1000 will be the limit once I get the last trait 49/50 so far

Comment: Both the other answers speak of a cap of 640: can you explain how you have been able to reach 980, and why you think 1000 is the cap?

Comment: The other answers are 2 years old at this point. DLCs have added new traits and each have 20 levels available. If you check the cited source in the second reply you can see the page now lists 50 traits. I'm not sure where you cap if DLC is not purchased.